# Toggle click, add an remove classes with Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, toggle

I created this slide menu, activated by a button. I'm using toggle(); to do that. But, I need two CSS effects: fadeIn and fadeOut. 
So, I put addClass(); to solve the problem. Sucess! But I can't do the same to fall the menu back. For example: Click on the button and add FadeIn class. The menu appears. Then, you have to click on the same button again, To remove fadeIn class and add the fadeOut class.

This is my actual code:

```
$(function(){
  $('.menu-btn').click(function(){
     $('.leftmenu').toggle(); 
     $('.leftmenu').addClass('fadeInLeft animated');

  });



});
```

And here my working example http://jsfiddle.net/N8S9y/

Any help will be much appreciated. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

`$(function(){
  $('.menu-btn').click(function(){`
   `$('.leftmenu').toggle(); 
     if($('.leftmenu').hasClass('fadeInLeft'))`
      {
 
          `$('.leftmenu').removeClass('fadeInLeft').addClass('fadeOut');`
     }
   else
      {

```
     $('.leftmenu').removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeInLeft');
  }
```

});

});`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass)**:

```
$('.leftmenu').toggleClass('FadeIn fadeOut');
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but didn't work. Appeared both classes at the same time.

Comment: @LucasHaas this will only work if the element has `FadeIn` class before the script is started.

Comment: Just add the FadeIn class within the HTML for the menu itself. So that we upset the sequence of it.